# Necesito que php muestre un texto u otro dependiendo un numero obtenido de una consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Primero que nada gracias por leer. Expongo la situacion:
realizo una consulta en mysql desde php en la que me entrega varias columnas, las expongo en una tabla con while y mysqli_fetch_array. Una de esas columnas (varible) se llama 'Tipo' y me devuelve numeros enteros (por ejemplo 1,3,5,8; lo que significa el tipo de comprobante ej: 1=factura, 2 nota de credito, etc); lo que necesitaria saber es como exponer el texto en la tabla de acuerdo al numero obtenido en cada fila (ahora mismo lo que hace el codigo es devolverme el numero en cuestion). Adjunto código

```
<?php
$consulta= "SELECT SUM(CtaCte.Debe - CtaCte.Haber) AS Saldo ,f.NroInterno AS IdFactura, 
f.Boca,  f.Tipo,  f.Letra,  f.Numero, f.Fecha, f.Moneda, f.Obs, f.MonedaCotizacion  
FROM Facturas f, CtaCte 
WHERE f.IdCliente = CtaCte.IdCliente 
AND (CtaCte.IdFactura = f.NroInterno OR CtaCte.IdFactura2 = f.NroInterno) 
AND CtaCte.IdCliente = 422 
AND f.Tipo IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8) 
AND f.Empresa = 1 AND CtaCte.Empresa = 1 
AND f.Sucursal = 2 AND CtaCte.Sucursal = 2 
AND (IsNull(CtaCte.Conciliado) OR CtaCte.Conciliado='N' OR CtaCte.Conciliado='') 
AND NOT f.Anulada = 'S' 
AND NOT CtaCte.Anulado = 'S' 
AND CtaCte.Fecha <= CURRENT_DATE() 
AND (f.Pagada = 'N' OR IsNull(Pagada)) 
GROUP BY f.NroInterno, f.Boca,  f.Tipo, f.Letra, f.Numero, f.Moneda, f.MonedaCotizacion, f.Obs, f.Fecha 
ORDER BY f.Fecha, f.Letra, f.Boca, f.Numero";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

?>

[[[ CODIGO CSS Y HTML OMITIDO ]]]

<?php
$total = 0;
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['IdFactura'] );?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Tipo'] );?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Boca'] );?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Numero'] );?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Letra'] );?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo date("d.m.y", strtotime($fila['Fecha']));?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Obs']);?></div></td>
        <td><div align="right">$ <?php echo number_format (($fila['Saldo']), 2, ',', '.');?></div></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias opciones:

**Con SQL**:

- Si tienes una tabla con los tipos haz JOIN y obtén de la consulta la descripción.
- Agrega la columna para descripción obteniendo el valor con un `CASE`.

```
    SELECT Tipo
         , CASE Tipo
             WHEN 1 THEN 'Factura'
             WHEN 2 THEN 'Nota de crédito'
           END descripcion
         ...
      FROM ...
```

```
<td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Descripcion'] );?></div></td>
```

**Con PHP:**

- Pon el catálogo en un arreglo

```
$tipos = array( 1 => 'Factura'
              , 2 => 'Nota de crédito'
              );
```

y obtén la descripción desde el arreglo por su clave.

```
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $tipos[$fila['Tipo']];?></div></td>
```

- Similar al anterior pero usando `switch` ó `if`s anidados; aunque implica una poco más código del necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo hice a traves de php como me indicaste y quedo de lujo. Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crearte una función y llamarlo en la vista:

```php
function tipoFactura($id) {
    switch($id) {
        case 1: return 'Factura';
        case 2: return 'Nota de credito';
        ...
    }
    return '';
}
```

Y en tu vista:

```php
<td><div align="center"><?php echo tipoFactura($fila['Tipo'] );?></div></td>
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona pero solo me muestra el primer resultado, no realiza el bucle del while. Que puedo estar haciendo mal